# DB2: Creating new database but no connection to database?

Tags: db2

**DB2**

I want to create a new database in a new instance. But when I use

```
db2 “CREATE DATABASE relodb ON /home/db2relo/db2relo/relodb/data DBPATH ON /home/db2relo/db2relo/relodb/metalog“
```

I get the following error:

```
DB21034E  The command was processed as an SQL statement because it was not a
valid Command Line Processor command.  During SQL processing it returned:
SQL1024N  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003
```

There's no database in the instance, that's why i can't connect to a existing database.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What appears in the db2diag.log after running this command?

Comment: is the instance running ? (db2start)

Comment: The quotation marks around the command look funny; make sure they are plain `"`s.

Answer (score 0):

Which versions of db2 has you installed first?
db2ls
Also how many instances you have in that version?
If you have differents versions installed you have to create a new instances for each version and a new fence with others groups?
this error looks like you are using a double ON you have to specific FROM and later ON the finally path.

Comment: DB21085I  This instance or install (instance name, where applicable: "db2relo")
uses "64" bits and DB2 code release "SQL11014" with level identifier
"0205010F".
Informational tokens are "DB2 v11.1.4.6", "s2102191900", "DYN2102191900AMD64",
and Fix Pack "6".
Product is installed at "/opt/ibm/db2/V11.1".

Thats what i get when i check the version.

I already had create a db2relo (user) and db2relof (fenced user) before creating the instance. Both are in the group db2relo.

But with these two ON i already created a database in another inctance. So it worked